# os.execl* not launching flask the same as os.system

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to launch a flask server as a process as part of a test suite.

```
import os

if __name__=='__main__'
    pth = "/fullpath/to/myapp.py"
    d,f = os.path.split(pth)
    os.chdir(d) # Not necessary (flash can launch from anywhere when full path in FLASK_APP
    os.environ["FLASK_APP"] = pth
    os.environ["FLASK_DEBUG"] = "1"

    # os.system("/usr/local/bin/flask run") # Succeeds!
    os.execl("/usr/local/bin/flask", "run") # Fails. Why ????!!
```

Flask runs (we find /usr/local/bin/flask), but gives me the standard usage error below, but doesn't say what's wrong.

If replace os.execl with `os.system("/usr/local/bin/flask run")` it works. If I execute '/use/bin/env' instead I can validate that FLASK_APP and FLASK_DEBUG are correctly set. If I run:

```
FLASK_APP=/fullpath/to/myapp.py FLASK_DEBUG=1  /usr/local/bin/flask
```

... everything works. Why would os.system work where os.exec* leads to flask thinking something is wrong?

(PS. the reason I want to use exec is because, in my test framework, I have already captured the present PID in the parent process, which I will SIGINT when my tests are complete. os.system starts flask with a new PID and flash don't get my SIGINT).

PPS. Also tried passing os.eniviron to the `os.exec*e` variants. No luck.

```
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  This shell command acts as general utility script for Flask applications.

  It loads the application configured (through the FLASK_APP environment
  variable) and then provides commands either provided by the application or
  Flask itself.

  The most useful commands are the "run" and "shell" command.

  Example usage:

    $ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
    $ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
    $ flask run

Options:
  --version  Show the flask version
  --help     Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  run    Runs a development server.
  shell  Runs a shell in the app context.
```

Comment: From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execl)  ... *In either case, the arguments to the child process should start with the name of the command being run*

Comment: Yeah I guess technically you're right -- although some examples would go a long way clarifying the usage there.

Comment: oh I agree ... I think most users of `os.exec*` have had to learn this rule the long way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because zeroth argument (`arg0`) should be same as path (or at least it has special meaning):

```
os.execl("/usr/local/bin/flask", "flask", "run")
```

or

```
os.execl("/usr/local/bin/flask", "/usr/local/bin/flask", "run")
```

is a correct way to run it.

Comment: Yes! This is it. Actually I think I've hit this before and forget the very intuitive solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a program through the shell, or through `os.system` (which goes through the shell), the shell implicitly inserts an extra command-line argument to the program at the beginning of the program's argument list. By default, this argument is the file name of the file being executed.

When you call one of the `os.exec*` functions, this argument is not inserted for you. You have to do it yourself:

```
os.execl("/usr/local/bin/flask", "/usr/local/bin/flask", "run")
```